# Mocking RestSharp response

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to write an unit test at the moment and i am having difficult with the mocking the RestSharp. The test i am trying to write is for the GetAll method.
This is the code that i am trying to test.

```
    public class Client: IClient
{
    public IRestClient RestClient { get; set; }
    public IOptions<ClientSettings>Settings { get; set; }
    public Client(IOptions<ClientSettings>options)
    {
        Settings = options;
        RestClient = new RestClient(options.Value.BaseUrl);
    }

    public async Task<List<EventDTO>> GetAll()
    {
        var allEvents = await RetrieveAllEvents();

        var data = TransformData(allEvents);

        return data;
    }

    private static List<EventDTO> TransformData(IEnumerable<Event> allEvents)
    {

        var data = allEvents.SelectMany(con =>
            con.Geometries.Select(geo =>
                new EventDTO
                {
                    Title = con.Title,
                    Id = con.Sources.FirstOrDefault()?.Id,
                    CategoriesTitle = con.Categories.FirstOrDefault()?.Title,
                    Closed = con.Closed,
                    DateTime = geo.Date
                })
        ).ToList();
        return data;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> RetrieveAllEvents()
    {
        var openEvents = await RetrieveEvent(Settings.Value.GetAllOpen);
        var closedEvents = await RetrieveEvent(Settings.Value.GetAllClosed);
        var allEvents = openEvents.Events.Concat(closedEvents.Events);
        return allEvents;
    }

    private async Task<RootObject> RetrieveEvent(string request)
    {
        var responseData = new RestRequest(request, Method.GET);

        var content = await RestClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(responseData);

        return content;
    }

}
```

When the code gets to this line, it just stops working. I tried putting in a try and catch around it see what the error is but it just blows the stack.

```
var data = await RestClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(responseData);
```

I saw an example online and i tried mocking the RestSharp

```
restClient.Setup(c => c.ExecuteAsync<EventDTO>(
                 Moq.It.IsAny<IRestRequest>(),
                 Moq.It.IsAny<Action<IRestResponse<EventDTO>, RestRequestAsyncHandle>>()))
                .Callback<IRestRequest, Action<IRestResponse<EventDTO>, RestRequestAsyncHandle>>((request, callback) =>
                {
                  var responseMock = new Mock<IRestResponse<EventDTO>>();
                  responseMock.Setup(r => r.Data).Returns(new EventDTO() { });
                  callback(responseMock.Object, null);
                });
```

Comment: Could you please provide more code of the test so I or anybody else can help you fix that issue and answer your questions. I also have one question - why are you trying to mock `ExecuteAsync` when you are actually using in your code `GetAsync`?

Comment: Hi Tony.
I am trying to write a test for the GetAll().
I am having difficulty mocking the line below.
 var content = await RestClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(responseData);
I think i went down the wrong path with how i setup the restClient Mock.
The ExecuteAsync is a overload for the setup for RestSharp. I could be doing that wrong.